# How to pass a mixture of strings and arrays to an executable from PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to call `vswhere.exe` to [find various Visual Studio executables](https://github.com/Microsoft/vswhere/wiki/Find-MSBuild) for CI purposes. In order to simplify this, I've created a wrapper function:

```
function Run-VsWhere { &("${env:ProgramFiles(x86)}/Microsoft Visual Studio/Installer/vswhere.exe") $args }

function Find-VSWherePath([string[]] $workloads, [string] $pathGlob) {
    Run-VsWhere -products * -prerelease -latest -requires $workloads -requiresAny -find $pathGlob
}
```

This works perfectly for single workloads, e.g. for MSBuild:

```
Find-VSWherePath "Microsoft.Component.MSBuild" "MSBuild/**/Bin/MSBuild.exe"
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Preview\MSBuild\Current\Bin\MSBuild.exe
```

... but falls apart for multiple ones like VSTest:

```
Find-VSWherePath "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.ManagedDesktop","Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.Web" "**/TestPlatform/vstest.console.exe"
> (nothing)
```

If I replace the call to `vswhere` with [a call to `echoargs`](https://github.com/Pscx/Pscx/tree/master/Src/EchoArgs), it demonstrates exactly what's going wrong. MSBuild:

```
> Arg 0 is <-products>
> Arg 1 is <*>
> Arg 2 is <-prerelease>
> Arg 3 is <-latest>
> Arg 4 is <-requires>
> Arg 5 is <Microsoft.Component.MSBuild>
> Arg 6 is <-requiresAny>
> Arg 7 is <-find>
> Arg 8 is <MSBuild/**/Bin/MSBuild.exe>
```

vs VSTest:

```
> Arg 0 is <-products>
> Arg 1 is <*>
> Arg 2 is <-prerelease>
> Arg 3 is <-latest>
> Arg 4 is <-requires>
> Arg 5 is <Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.ManagedDesktop Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.Web>
> Arg 6 is <-requiresAny>
> Arg 7 is <-find>
> Arg 8 is <**/TestPlatform/vstest.console.exe>
```

The issue is that the `$workloads` parameter is being passed to `Run-VsWhere` as a **single parameter joined by a space**, instead of one parameter **per element in the array** - how can I force it to pass as I need? I've tried every combination of splatting, splitting, joining, single-quoting, double-quoting... but nothing seems to work.

Comment: `function Run-VsWhere { "..." $args }` should throw an error when trying to define the function. Did you omit the call operator?

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers You are correct, I've fixed the code.

Comment: Try echoing `"${env:ProgramFiles(x86)}/..." $args` instead of invoking the program. Does it show the commandline you expect? Do you get a result when running that commandine manually?

Comment: Try `@args` instead of `$args`. That should unroll the array.

Comment: Bloody beautiful @AnsgarWiechers! Please post that as an answer so I can give you the richly-deserved credit!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the automatic variable `$args` passes the arguments as they're provided, meaning that an array argument nested in `$args` is passed as-is (i.e. remains an array). Use [splatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting?view=powershell-3.0) (`@args`) to flatten/unroll nested arrays.

```
function Run-VsWhere {
    & "${env:ProgramFiles(x86)}/Microsoft Visual Studio/Installer/vswhere.exe" @args
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible your second call to `Find-VSWherePath` does not result in anything because the specified workloads are not available? I tried the code below and it does work.

```
function Find-VSWherePath([string[]] $workloads, [string] $pathGlob) {
    . "${env:ProgramFiles(x86)}/Microsoft Visual Studio/Installer/vswhere.exe" -products * -prerelease -latest -requires $workloads -requiresAny -find $pathGlob
}

clear

"This works"
Find-VSWherePath "Microsoft.Component.MSBuild" "MSBuild/**/Bin/MSBuild.exe"

"No result"
Find-VSWherePath "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.Web" "MSBuild/**/Bin/MSBuild.exe"

"Try two workloads, the first is not available, but the second is. This also works."
Find-VSWherePath "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.Web","Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.NuGet" "MSBuild/**/Bin/MSBuild.exe"
```

Comment: Sorry for wasting your time, I made a typo in the question, please see the update.